# xml code to format bold snippet in word document template issue

Tags: python, xml, ms-word

I am constructing a sentence to insert into a word xml template. My python 2.7 code is below

```
#Create a list using a function that returns a comma formatted list of dealers

if len(myList) > 0:
    if len(myList) > 1:
        testText = list_format(myList) + " dealers."
    else:
        myText = myList[0] + " dealer."

#Contruct sentence

    #myBlurb = "<w:cr/><w:r><w:rPr><w:b/></w:rPr><w:t>My Favorite Cars - </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t> My favorite cars are available at </w:t></w:r>"  + myText + "<w:cr/>"
    myBlurb = "<w:cr/>My Favorite Cars - My favorite cars are available at " + myText + "<w:cr/>"
else:
    myBlurb = ""
```

If a list exists (not = 0) Then

I am trying to get the following output:

**My Favorite Cars -** My favorite cars are available at (list of dealers) dealers.

There is a newline above and below this line. The first three words and the dash are bold. All other words are not bold.

This works but contains no bold text

```
myBlurb = "<w:cr/>My Favorite Cars - My favorite cars are available at " + myText + "<w:cr/>"
```

But when I try to bold, it bombs. It does not seem to like either of these `(+ myText + "<w:cr/>")` (separately or together) appended on the end.

This does not work

```
myBlurb = "<w:cr/><w:r><w:rPr><w:b/></w:rPr><w:t>My Favorite Cars - </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t> My favorite cars are available at </w:t></w:r>"  + myText + "<w:cr/
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always helps if you describe how "This does not work" in detail, but I think this is what you're missing (just the code from the end of the entire string, for clarity's sake):

```
</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>"  + myText + "< /w:t></w:r><w:cr/>"
```

`myText` should be handled just like the static runs you want to write to the document - it needs to be declared as a run containing text.

Comment: Sorry. Got an "unknown error" message. Didn't see it as much help. You are correct. This was the piece I was missing. I did not realize I needed to wrap the text element around the variable. Thank you.